# how to get java process virtual memory in windows

Tags: java, windows, memory, sigar

I'm trying to get the physical and virtual memeory that my Java process is using in Windows system, like the taskmgr does.

I'm able to get the physical memory of my Java progress, but I cannot get the virtual memory. Now I'm thinking using Windows API to get the process virtual memory, however, I cannot find the function that is working.

Is there another way to get the virtual memory of my java progress?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be specific when you ask questions, showing your (related!) code, what the problem is, what you tried to fix it, what you got and what you expected instead.

Comment: Edited your question a bit for spelling/grammar/readability. Though the majority of your question still makes no sense to me, maybe you could ask someone you know to help you out forming the question and then updating it for us?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
long size = 0;
        OperatingSystemMXBean osm = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        if (null != osm) {
            size = osm.getCommittedVirtualMemorySize() / 1024L;
        }
```